# Clarifiaction on JSON format

Tags: json

Need clarifiaction of the JSON format.

I streamed this JSON file from twitterstream,but while checking on JSONLint,I am getting following error.

```
Error: Parse error on line 11:
...1554180840158"   }} {    "delete": {     "st
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

JSON Code:-

```
{
    "delete": {
        "status": {
            "id": 1038195538020196352,
            "id_str": "1038195538020196352",
            "user_id": 1730046890,
            "user_id_str": "1730046890"
        },
        "timestamp_ms": "1554180840158"
    }
} {
    "delete": {
        "status": {
            "id": 761199968916955136,
            "id_str": "761199968916955136",
            "user_id": 715099043609751552,
            "user_id_str": "715099043609751552"
        },
        "timestamp_ms": "1554180840228"
    }
}
```

Comment: What you posted is not JSON, it's 2 JSON objects separated by space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONLint is complaining that it's not a valid object. Realistically, you have two objects in your JSON example. Each one passes JSONLint but your error has to do with the "} {" in the middle. For this entire example to parse, you need a [ at the very beginning, a comma in the middle of the two objects e.g. }, { and a ] at the end. See the following

```
[{
    "delete": {
        "status": {
            "id": 1038195538020196352,
            "id_str": "1038195538020196352",
            "user_id": 1730046890,
            "user_id_str": "1730046890"
        },
        "timestamp_ms": "1554180840158"
    }
}, {
    "delete": {
        "status": {
            "id": 761199968916955136,
            "id_str": "761199968916955136",
            "user_id": 715099043609751552,
            "user_id_str": "715099043609751552"
        },
        "timestamp_ms": "1554180840228"
    }
}]
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie,I got it now.So,twitter is not sending the whole file as a JSON,instead sending multiple JSON objects bundled together.

Answer (score 0):

That is not JSON - it's two JSON objects separated by a space. You need to place them into an array:

```
[{
    "delete": {
        "status": {
            "id": 1038195538020196352,
            "id_str": "1038195538020196352",
            "user_id": 1730046890,
            "user_id_str": "1730046890"
        },
        "timestamp_ms": "1554180840158"
    }
}, {
    "delete": {
        "status": {
            "id": 761199968916955136,
            "id_str": "761199968916955136",
            "user_id": 715099043609751552,
            "user_id_str": "715099043609751552"
        },
        "timestamp_ms": "1554180840228"
    }
}]
```